# When to use helper method in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm not sure when to use a helper method in solving recursive problems in binary tree vs when to not use one. For example, in lowest common ancestor of Binary tree, the code can be done without a helper method (https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-tree/) whereas in problem Balanced Binary tree (https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/) we use a helper method. How can I distinguish when to use one?

For my lowest common ancestor the solution is this:

```java
public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
    if(root == null){
        return null;
    }
    if(root == p || root == q){
        return root;
    }
    TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
    TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);

    if(left != null && right != null){
        return root;
    }
    if(right == null && left == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if(right != null && left == null){
        return right;
    }else{
        return left;
    }
}
```

And for something like finding a balanced binary tree the code is like this:

```java
class Solution {
    boolean bal = true;
    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        maxHeight(root);
        return bal;
    }
    public int maxHeight(TreeNode root){
        if(root == null){
            return 0;
        }
        int left = maxHeight(root.left);
        int right = maxHeight(root.right);

        int diff = Math.abs(left - right);

        if(diff > 1){
            bal = false;
        }
        return Math.max(left, right)+1;
    }
}
```

The balanced tree has a helper method `maxHeight`, while the `lowestCommonAncestor` does not.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "helper method", what language you're referring to, and explain why you think one of these problem demands one?

Comment: A helper function is typically used when you need additional parameters to transport/represent the state values in your recursion scheme.

Comment: @CollinD I am coding in java, for LCA, it recursively calls itself, but for balanced tree it uses a helper maxHeight to run

Comment: It's not good practice to use a field to communicate the result of the method, as you have with `bal`: for instance, you never reset `bal` to `true`, so you would get the wrong result for `isBalanced` if you invoke it first for a non-balanced tree, then a balanced tree.

Comment: To be clear you’re not exactly comparing Apples to Apples. Your first code isn’t the typical format that Leetcode wants. It’s just a *function*. The second code though is the general format of Leetcode where it has the `Solution` *class*. Like it’s _possible_ that certain Leetcode challenges can be written recursively while using the original syntax that Leetcode provides. It really depends on the question and how you want to code it.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple aspects to the answer:

- Recursion is never necessary.
- ... but there's one extremely common way helpers are used.

### Recursion is never necessary.

You never *have to* recurse. Every recursive solution can trivially be rewritten as a solution that uses one loop. Here's, in essence, how that works: (As an example, we use fibonacci, that evergreen textbook example for recursion, and the non-recursive solution is needlessly complicated; the point of these example is to show how *any* recursive algorithm can be rewritten!)

```
// recursive function:

void fibR(int n) {
  return switch (n) {
    case 0 -> 0;
    case 1, 2 -> 1;
    default -> fibR(n-2) + fibR(n-1);
  };
}

// loop rewrite:

static class FibJob {
  int n;
  FibJob(int n) {this.n = n;}
}

int fibL(int n) {
  var jobs = new ArrayDeque<FibJob>();
  jobs.add(new FibJob(n));

  int total = 0;
  while (!jobs.isEmpty()) {
    FibJob job = jobs.pollFirst();
    switch (job.n) {
      case 0 -> total += 0;
      case 1, 2 -> total += 1;
      default -> {
        jobs.add(new FibJob(job.n - 2));
        jobs.add(new FibJob(job.n - 1));
      }
    };
  }

  return total;
}
```

NB: This code misses some significant optimisations and of course using a `FibJob` object just to store a single int value is a needless complication, but it shows how this can be applied to a recursive algorithm that has more than a single input value.

---

### Helper methods

Recursion taken as a concept involves:

An algorithm that takes in some parameters, and does a very simple calculation using [A] those parameters, and [B] 1 or more calls to itself, but with parameters that are moving towards 'simpler' values. In addition, the algorithm will answer without recursion for the simplest possible values (the 'base case').

The key point that causes helper methods to naturally appear is in how information is passed from one invocation to the next. For example, for fib it's real easy - the only parameter that needs to be passed in is the value you want (i.e. '8' in: "I want the 8th fibonacci number"), and the only value that needs to be passed 'back' is the result.

This is **the exact same** as the original question. This is why you rarely see a helper method show up for example recursive implementations of fib.

There are other recursive algorithms where there is a mismatch between what is passed and what is commonly stated.

For example, imagine a pathfinder algorithm that attempts to find the shortest path between A and Z, given a big 'graph' listing which roads exist between letters, and how long they are. Imagining that all roads always go from an earlier letter to a later letter (always from A to C, never from C to A), then we can apply a recursive algorithm:

```
Map<Character, Map<Character, Integer>> graph = ...;

int navigate(char from, int soFar) {
  if (from == 'Z') return soFar;
  Map<Character, Integer> destinations = graph.getOrDefault(from, Map.of());
  int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  for (var entry : destinations.entrySet()) {
    int kmsToDestination = entry.getValue();
    char destination = entry.getKey();
    minimum = Math.min(navigate(destination, soFar + kmsToDestination));
  }
  return minimum;
}
```

There is just one problem with this algorithm: The caller doesn't really understand why `soFar` is even there as a parameter. It's crucial for this particular algorithm, but it's an implementation detail when looking at this algorithm 'from the outside'. The caller really just wants to go: Hey, I'm at C. What's the shortest amount of kilometers if I want to get to Z? They just want to tell you 'C'. They don't want to tell you: Oh, and we're starting, so we have 0 kms on the odometer so far.

Hence, helper method:

```
int navigate(char from) {
  return navigate(from, 0);
}
```

These helpers virtually always pass a bunch of 'unit' (base) values as additional parameters: 0 (for additive algorithms), 1 (for multiplicative), or an empty list/set/map, or an empty string.

The helper still isn't *necessary* of course, just, nice: You don't really want to have to explain to callers that this `soFar` thing exists and what it is meant to represent. Callers are unlikely to want the functionality, it'll just be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call some funtion repeatedly then well you need a seperate funtion.

This is because the original function that Leetcode provides can’t be called repeatedly because it doesn’t suit your needs. If you change its signature then Leetcode won’t be able to call it.

The 2nd code you shared has a recursive algorithm. Hence the need to write a recursive (helper) function. The main function just needs to figure out what are the correct values to pass to the helper function.

In this case it just happens to be `root`. Often it’s `root` and passing a currentValue. Like the sum of the nodes till that node. Or something else. Which if you again are starting from the root then the sum would just be the root value itself.